# Java: access method annotation by method

Tags: java, annotations

We want to handle system properties in a non-central way, that we

- simply and quickly can access them,
- have default values,
- for ints have minimum and maximum values,
- have documentation string beside it,
- can access **all** supported properties with their default values, ranges and documentation programmatically.

Until now we are doing it that way:

```
private static final int MAX_INFO_COUNT = MyProperties.getProp(
    "app.maxInfoCount", // property name
     10, // default value
      1, // min value
    100, // max value
    "This defines the maximum count ..." // description for user
);
```

Problem is that with this approach we only can collect properties that are already handled in performed code at this time, but not all properties in the whole application.

We could mark the property read method somehow with an annotation for being able to collect them across the application using reflection, but then we would have either to duplicate the information in the annotation and the property read method or somehow access one from the other (is this possible?).